# Iredmail - Postfix: Mail Server receive emails but not send

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp, email-server, iredmail

I have a server with *iredmail* configured and I can't send email. I receive that message in *postfix* log:

> 00C3CC04FA: to=jeanpierre.carvalho@solfut.com, relay=none, delay=4797, delays=4766/0.04/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.solfut.com[80.172.244.187]:25: Connection timed out)

With Gmail happens the same.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no recipient : `to=`. Edit your post to explain how you send mails

Comment: Copy Error --' i edited.

Comment: If you do in a shell : `echo | telnet mail.solfut.com 25` what is the output ?

Comment: Its: Trying 80.172.244.187... and for google: Trying 74.125.130.26...

Answer (score 0):

When you test the remote mail server with

```
echo | telnet mail.solfut.com 25
```

you should get `Connected to mail.solfut.com`.

If not, then you have a 'simple network issue'.

Try to disable your firewall (or better allow outcoming port TCP 25) in your firewall.

Comment: Its a google problem but i cant fix that.. :(

Comment: Blocked traffic

Google Compute Engine blocks or restricts traffic through all of the following ports/protocols between the Internet and virtual machines, as well as between two virtual machines when traffic is addressed to their public IP addresses (this also includes load-balanced addresses).